# Help me understand my mod_wsgi Django config file

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I was wondering why this works:

```
sys.path.append('/home/user/django')
sys.path.append('/home/user/django/mysite')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```

but this doesn't?

```
sys.path.append('/home/user/django')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```

I thought that adding the django folder would automatically make all projects/folders in it available to python? But apparantly I have to add the project as well, or it gives me the error 'settings not found'.

Notice that it doesn't say 'mysite.settings not found' which would indicate it *does* find my 'mysite' folder..

Comment: What exactly do `this works` and `this doesn't` mean ?

Comment: this works = the mysite/settings.py is found and parsed.

Comment: doesn't work=  ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if in your settings.py you have an import to a module that's inside the mysite directory, this import fails and that's why you get the ImportError.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://codespatter.com/2009/04/10/how-to-add-locations-to-python-path-for-reusable-django-apps/